# AttributeError: type object 'Factory' has no attribute '_get_provider_class'

Tags: pytest-django

when launching paytests it gives an error AttributeError: type object 'Factory' has no attribute '_get_provider_class'  I'm learning to program and don't know what to do

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

That method was [removed](https://github.com/joke2k/faker/commit/60f0941a80519ff9106ec1b4dcffcbc7e23139e5#diff-eab89d17cb83f13fdcda34aa81fe74d2e483492d23e4cc20e00f74cc1f5f286aL67) in Faker 12.1.0. If you're not using Faker directly, this can also occur in certain versions of Mixer before the dependency was [pinned](https://github.com/klen/mixer/pull/146).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem is with Faker library.

I have managed to solve it with these commands (with venv activated):

```
$ pip uninstall Faker
$ pip install Faker==6.0.0
```

Maybe you want to try different versions instead of 6.0.0